# Why does webkit through capybara get different results than CasperJS?

Tags: webkit, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm a bit new to the plethora of scraping technologies available so I've been testing out a bunch.  One test page I'm looking at is [here](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Buddha-Bodai-Vegetarian-Restaurant/117609928256672?sk=info).  I've noticed that my scraper running through Capybara is returning the results I would expect - HTML after the JS runs.  Here is the code:

```
  class Scraper
    include Capybara::DSL

    Capybara.run_server = false
    Capybara.current_driver = :webkit

    def test_scrape      
      visit "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Buddha-Bodai-Vegetarian-Restaurant/117609928256672?sk=info"
      if body.match /pagelet_nearby_places_results/
        has_xpath?("//div[@id='pagelet_nearby_places_results']")
      end
      body
    end
  end
```

This is obviously a very basic test.  You can see this loaded properly by looking into the HTML for the Foursquare link on the page, for example.

```
<a class="uiIconText" href="https://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Ffoursquare.com%2Fv%2Fbuddha-bodai%2F459b830af964a5208b401fe3%3Fref%3Datw&amp;h=0AQH4z1yv&amp;s=1"
...
```

I'm also testing a CasperJS solution implemented as shown below:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  pageSettings: {
    javascriptEnabled: true,
    loadImages: false,
    loadPlugins: false,
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.9 Safari/536.5'
  }
});


result = {};

casper.start("https://www.facebook.com/pages/Buddha-Bodai-Vegetarian-Restaurant/117609928256672?sk=info", function() {
    var body = this.getHTML();
    if(body.indexOf('pagelet_nearby_places_results') >= 0){
        casper.waitForSelector('div#pagelet_nearby_places_results', function() {
           result.html = this.getHTML();
        });
    }else{
        result.html = body;
    }    
});

casper.run(function complete() {
    this.echo(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
    this.exit();
});
```

For this I get different results which seems like HTML before the JS loads.  The foursquare link in this case is commented out and inside a code tag:

```
<code class="hidden_elem" id="u_0_i"><!-- <div class="_5ay5"><div data-gt="{&quot;vertex_section&quot;:&quot;VertexLinksSection&quot;}"><div class="_gl"><div class="_117 _4qd"><h3>Links</h3></div><div class="_gm"><ul class="uiList _4kg _6-h _6-j _6-i"><li class="_6zy"><table class="uiGrid _51mz" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr class="_51mx"><td class="_51m-"><a class="uiIconText" href="https://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Ffoursquare.com%2Fv%2Fbuddha-bodai%2F459b830af964a5208b401fe3%3Fref%3Datw&amp;h=UAQG_81FD&amp;s=1"
...
```

The difference is strange for two reasons:
1. Apparently CasperJS (which sits on PhantomJS) cannot return HTML before JS runs.  That's the entire point of the PhantomJS.
2. Both of my solutions are based on webkit

Note that I've also tried just having Casper wait for like 5 seconds (should be enough time) to help rule out waitForSelector acting funny.  Given this is a very simple test case, I'm hoping someone can give some insight into why the results are different.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug so I logged it here:
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11964